# Use join field as replace - ArcGIS Pro/Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, replace

I am looking for a tool that replaces specific values from an existing shapefile field, these specific values need to come from a separated CSV or Excel table.

For example, my shapefile has the field "ID" (values: 1,2,3,4,5) and another field "Test" (values A,A,A,A,A)

My CSV or Excel table has the columns "ID" (values: 1,2,3) and another column "Test" (values B,B,B)

As a result, I need the shapefile to have the in field "Test" the values B,B,B,A,A.

What I mean by that is that the join should replace values in the field "Test" for the matched IDs and not create another column.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that using ArcGIS Pro and preferably Model Builder?

Comment: Have you determined and tested the steps you want to automate with Model Builder?  For example, have you tested making a join and then running Calculate Field to update the shape file's "Test" field?

Comment: This would be a fairly basic task in Python. By restricting yourself to ModelBuilder you reduce your options.

Comment: Yes, Join Field + Calculate Field + Delete old field was my idea of a temporary solution. But this is very inefficient in a 2.3M records dataset, I thought there could be a more straightforward solution

Comment: @Fjord that's how I would do it model builder. You don't state in your question that efficiency is an issue, so if this is a one-time processing step who cares?